# Error: "Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1" when passing Mat object from java to jni function

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk, segmentation-fault

I am running the video camera using the `OpenCV` function. I pass the `Mat` object to the `jni` function it works for awhile, them the error:

```
10-10 13:03:17.978: A/libc(28693): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x9 in tid 28791 (Thread-5418)
```

Java code that runs the camera and calls the jni function:

```
package com.adhamenaya;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.opencv.android.BaseLoaderCallback;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2;
import org.opencv.android.LoaderCallbackInterface;
import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
//import org.opencv.highgui.Highgui;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements CvCameraViewListener2,
        OnTouchListener {

    private static final String TAG = "OCVSample::Activity";
    private Mat mRgba;
    private Mat mGray;
    private CameraBridgeViewBase mOpenCvCameraView;

    private ArrayList<Mat> mats = new ArrayList<Mat>();

    private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
        @Override
        public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
            switch (status) {
            case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS: {
                Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");
                mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
                mOpenCvCameraView.setOnTouchListener(MainActivity.this);

            }
                break;
            default: {
                super.onManagerConnected(status);
            }
                break;
            }
        }
    };

    public MainActivity() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Instantiated new " + this.getClass());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(TAG, "called onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Native.loadlibs();


        mOpenCvCameraView = (CameraBridgeViewBase) findViewById(R.id.cam_view);
        mOpenCvCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
        mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);

        Native.setup(mFaceCascadeFile, mNoseCascadeFile, mLandmarks);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mOpenCvCameraView != null)
            mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_3, this,
                mLoaderCallback);
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mOpenCvCameraView != null)
            mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
    }

    public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
        mGray = new Mat();
        mRgba = new Mat();
    }

    public void onCameraViewStopped() {
    }

    public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
        mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
        Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba, mGray, Imgproc.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY);
        Native.runJni(mFaceCascadeFile, mNoseCascadeFile, mLandmarks,
                mRgba.getNativeObjAddr());

        return mRgba;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }


}
```

Jni function:

```
JNIEXPORT jbyteArray JNICALL Java_com_adhamenaya_Native_runJni(JNIEnv * env,
        jobject obj, jstring faceCascadeFile, jstring noseCascadeFile,
        jstring landmarks, jlong frame) {

    cv::Mat& inFrame = *(cv::Mat*) frame;

    if (!gsys.loadFaceCascade(faceCascadeFnameStr)) {
        LOG("Could not load face cascade");
        gsys.loadFaceCascade(faceCascadeFnameStr);
    } else {
        LOG("Face cascade: OK");

    }

    if (!gsys.loadNoseCascade(noseCascadeFnameStr)) {
        LOG("Could not load nose cascade");
        gsys.loadNoseCascade(noseCascadeFnameStr);

    } else {
        LOG("Nose cascade: OK");

    }

    gsys.setFrameRate(30);
    gsys.setProgramState(DETECT);

    clock_t tin, tout = 0;

    cv::flip(inFrame, inFrame, 0);
    cv::transpose(inFrame, inFrame);

    dlib::shape_predictor pose_model;
    dlib::deserialize(landmarksStr) >> pose_model;


     gsys.setCurrentFrame(inFrame);

     tin = clock();
     trigger_hr(gsys, faces, pose_model);

     // Process the frame
     size_t spm;
     float motionStrengthX, motionStrengthY;
     float phiYaw = -0xFFFFFFFF, thetaPitch = -0xFFFFFFFF;

     if (faces.size()) {
     faces[0].getSpm(gsys, spm, motionStrengthX, motionStrengthY);
     faces[0].getFacePose(phiYaw, thetaPitch);
     }

     tout = tout + clock() - tin;
     if ((gsys.getFrameCount() % 30) == 29) {
     double secs_between_frames = (double) (tout) / (CLOCKS_PER_SEC * 30.0f);
     printf("FPS = %2.2f\n", 1.0f / secs_between_frames);
     LOG("FPS = %2.2f ", 1.0f / secs_between_frames);
     tout = 0;
     }

     char spmText[100];

     //sprintf(spmText,
     //     "SPM = %zu, P = %2.2f, T = %2.2f, MS-X = %2.2f, MS-Y = %2.2f", spm,
     //     phiYaw, thetaPitch, motionStrengthX, motionStrengthY);

     LOG("SPM = %zu, P = %2.2f, T = %2.2f, MS-X = %2.2f, MS-Y = %2.2f", spm,
     phiYaw, thetaPitch, motionStrengthX, motionStrengthY);

    std::string str;
    str = "SPM=";

    jbyteArray arr = env->NewByteArray(str.length());
    env->SetByteArrayRegion(arr, 0, str.length(), (jbyte*) str.c_str());

    return arr;

}
```

Kindly help me.

Comment: Have you identified the line where the crash happens? The relevant portion of the log would be valuable. Once you identify the line, print the data that are inputs to the statement on that line.

Comment: @18446744073709551615 thank you for your comment, I could figure out the problem by myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After two days of searching online, I could figure out that the problem is because of the 'Memory leak', and this happens when I am reading the frames from a video and send them the `jni` function, without releasing frames after finishing working on them, so always I will have the frames in the memory.

What I did is to move the Mat object in the `C++` code outside the scope of the function and make it a class scope object, so it will not create a new object each time the function is called.

Also, I called:

```
inFrame.release();
```

to free the memory after finishing  working on it.