# Android Real Time DFT in Camera View using OpenCV

Tags: android, opencv, dft

I've been struggling to implement an Android application that applies DFT direct at the camera view. Doing a research at stackoverflow, I could find the following topics:

[SOLVED - Load Image in Mat and Display after DFT process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23165651/solved-load-image-in-mat-and-display-after-dft-process)

[SOLVED - Load Image in Mat and Display after DFT process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23165651/solved-load-image-in-mat-and-display-after-dft-process?lq=1)

[Convert OpenCv DCT to Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22910047/convert-opencv-dct-to-android)

I've also tried a different solution using JNI:
http://allaboutee.com/2011/11/12/discrete-fourier-transform-in-android-with-opencv/

And then I could implement my main Activity Code:

```
package ch.hepia.lsn.opencv_native_androidstudio;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import org.opencv.android.BaseLoaderCallback;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import org.opencv.android.LoaderCallbackInterface;
import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.Rect;
import org.opencv.core.Size;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2 {
    private static final String TAG = "OCVSample::Activity";

    private CameraBridgeViewBase mOpenCvCameraView;

    private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
        @Override
        public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
            switch (status) {
                case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS: {
                    Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");
                    mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
                }
                break;
                default: {
                    super.onManagerConnected(status);
                }
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Load ndk built module, as specified
        // in moduleName in build.gradle
        System.loadLibrary("native");

        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mOpenCvCameraView = (CameraBridgeViewBase) findViewById(R.id.main_surface);
        mOpenCvCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
        mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        disableCamera();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Internal OpenCV library not found. Using OpenCV Manager for initialization");
            OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_3_0_0, this, mLoaderCallback);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "OpenCV library found inside package. Using it!");
            mLoaderCallback.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS);
        }
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        disableCamera();
    }

    public void disableCamera() {
        if (mOpenCvCameraView != null)
            mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
    }

    public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
    }

    public void onCameraViewStopped() {
    }

    private Mat getDFT(Mat singleChannel) {

        singleChannel.convertTo(singleChannel, CvType.CV_64FC1);

        int m = Core.getOptimalDFTSize(singleChannel.rows());
        int n = Core.getOptimalDFTSize(singleChannel.cols()); // on the border
        // add zero
        // values
        // Imgproc.copyMakeBorder(image1,
        // padded, 0, m -
        // image1.rows(), 0, n

        Mat padded = new Mat(new Size(n, m), CvType.CV_64FC1); // expand input
        // image to
        // optimal size

        Core.copyMakeBorder(singleChannel, padded, 0, m - singleChannel.rows(), 0,
                n - singleChannel.cols(), Core.BORDER_CONSTANT);

        List<Mat> planes = new ArrayList<Mat>();
        planes.add(padded);
        planes.add(Mat.zeros(padded.rows(), padded.cols(), CvType.CV_64FC1));

        Mat complexI = Mat.zeros(padded.rows(), padded.cols(), CvType.CV_64FC2);

        Mat complexI2 = Mat
                .zeros(padded.rows(), padded.cols(), CvType.CV_64FC2);

        Core.merge(planes, complexI); // Add to the expanded another plane with
        // zeros

        Core.dft(complexI, complexI2); // this way the result may fit in the
        // source matrix

        // compute the magnitude and switch to logarithmic scale
        // => log(1 + sqrt(Re(DFT(I))^2 + Im(DFT(I))^2))
        Core.split(complexI2, planes); // planes[0] = Re(DFT(I), planes[1] =
        // Im(DFT(I))

        Mat mag = new Mat(planes.get(0).size(), planes.get(0).type());

        Core.magnitude(planes.get(0), planes.get(1), mag);// planes[0]
        // =
        // magnitude

        Mat magI = mag;
        Mat magI2 = new Mat(magI.size(), magI.type());
        Mat magI3 = new Mat(magI.size(), magI.type());
        Mat magI4 = new Mat(magI.size(), magI.type());
        Mat magI5 = new Mat(magI.size(), magI.type());

        Core.add(magI, Mat.ones(padded.rows(), padded.cols(), CvType.CV_64FC1),
                magI2); // switch to logarithmic scale
        Core.log(magI2, magI3);

        Mat crop = new Mat(magI3, new Rect(0, 0, magI3.cols() & -2,
                magI3.rows() & -2));

        magI4 = crop.clone();

        // rearrange the quadrants of Fourier image so that the origin is at the
        // image center
        int cx = magI4.cols() / 2;
        int cy = magI4.rows() / 2;

        Rect q0Rect = new Rect(0, 0, cx, cy);
        Rect q1Rect = new Rect(cx, 0, cx, cy);
        Rect q2Rect = new Rect(0, cy, cx, cy);
        Rect q3Rect = new Rect(cx, cy, cx, cy);

        Mat q0 = new Mat(magI4, q0Rect); // Top-Left - Create a ROI per quadrant
        Mat q1 = new Mat(magI4, q1Rect); // Top-Right
        Mat q2 = new Mat(magI4, q2Rect); // Bottom-Left
        Mat q3 = new Mat(magI4, q3Rect); // Bottom-Right

        Mat tmp = new Mat(); // swap quadrants (Top-Left with Bottom-Right)
        q0.copyTo(tmp);
        q3.copyTo(q0);
        tmp.copyTo(q3);

        q1.copyTo(tmp); // swap quadrant (Top-Right with Bottom-Left)
        q2.copyTo(q1);
        tmp.copyTo(q2);

        Core.normalize(magI4, magI5, 0, 255, Core.NORM_MINMAX);

        Mat realResult = new Mat(magI5.size(), CvType.CV_8UC1);

        magI5.convertTo(realResult, CvType.CV_8UC1);

        return realResult;
    }

    public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
        //System.out.print("teste");
        Mat matGray = inputFrame.gray();
        return getDFT(inputFrame.gray());
    }
}
```

But the problem is, I still getting this error:

> 07-03 22:46:46.205
>   13700-28322/ch.hepia.lsn.opencv_native_androidstudio A/libc: Fatal
>   signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x10 in tid 28322
>   (Thread-9802)

Which I think it is because of some processing limitation, since I just copied the code that worked with others users using general images.

My questions are:

- How can I check if this error is due a processing limitation?
- There are any other way to implement it using OpenCV or other library?

Thank you.

Comment: Does it crash immediatly or after a while like in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33052806/error-fatal-signal-11-sigsegv-code-1-when-passing-mat-object-from-java-to and the second question is: is your code working without the DFT? If it is then the error is in DFT. If it is not working even without DFT then the error is somewhere else.

Comment: The app seems to crash immediately, but if I look at the logcast I can see that it works like 3~5 times, and then crash.
It was working without the DFT, if I make the output just the frame in gray it works fine.

Comment: Then the issue is in releasing resources. You are creating a lot of matrices but you aren't releasing the memory. Even java doesn't release it for you because it doesn't know about allocated resources in native lib. So make sure to call relase method before return on every mat you have created except the one you are returning.

Comment: Hello,
I've add some release() at the code, and I still getting the same error.
Also I've added some log before the dft algorithm and after it. And the result showed that the dft function just run once:
07-04 18:38:23.102 22199-22328/ch.hepia.lsn.opencv_native_androidstudio W/myApp: before dft
07-04 18:38:23.122 

22199-22199/ch.hepia.lsn.opencv_native_androidstudio D/JavaCameraView: Preview Frame received. Frame size: 1775616
07-04 18:38:23.172 

22199-22199/ch.hepia.lsn.opencv_native_androidstudio D/JavaCameraView: Preview Frame received. Frame size: 1775616
(...)
Breaks

Comment: I think I need something to make the camera stops capturing frame, wait to process the dft, and then show it on screen. But I can't find anything source that talks about it.

Comment: UPDATE: The function breaks at the line of
Core.add(magI, Mat.ones(padded.rows(), padded.cols(), CvType.CV_64FC1), magI2);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've ported the code I originally posted to Android Studio (from Eclipse) and OpenCV 3.1.0. I think there is an issue with the Core.add() function in this version of openCV - see the post [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/15757/java-api-coreadd-method-not-working-how-to-add-2-mats/)

I used as suggested Core.addWeighted() and I could at least get the dft to display but not very long before it ran out of memory. I *think* functions like split also use add() so I think we need to look at a fix for that problem in openCV.

The code I posted can be improved to make better use of resources, for example, keep static allocations of the key arrays, don't keep calling size() but again hold that statically, reduce the number of allocated Mats etc. You can also reduce the size of the captured image as the Mats can get huge on more modern phones (I have Samsung S6), so using

```
mOpenCvCameraView.setMaxFrameSize(176, 152);
```

or whatever size is more manageable.

If you want to reduce the number of frame process then keep a static counter that you increment on every frame capture and only call getDFT() if the counter is divisible by say 5, 10 or whatever to only process those every 5th, 10th frame etc.

Comment: Hi Timegalore,
First of all, thank you for answering. Using addWeighted solved the problem but as result my function gives me black frame.
I'm wondering if I'm returning the wrong matrix at getDFT function, in this case I'm returning: realResult.

Comment: How do you do the addWeighted? I used:  

Core.addWeighted(magI, 1, Mat.ones(padded.rows(), padded.cols(), CvType.CV_64FC1), 1, 0,
                magI2);

Comment: I'm using the same parameters, at the middle of the code execution I got this error:
http://pastebin.com/G0fF5Hah

The only thing I added different than core.addWeighted was:
mOpenCvCameraView.setMaxFrameSize(176, 152);

I'm using a samsung s6 as well.

Comment: Ok, I just reduce the quality of the image capture by the camera and could get some results.
It seems that the problem is because of that. Now I think the next step is to thing in ways to free memory and smart use of image processing.
Thank you timegalore!